# Plot uniform background color with seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, graphics, seaborn

When using `seaborn.jointplot` with a Kernel Density Estimation, the background of the KDE does not span the whole background of the figure, resulting in ugly white margins, as shown here:
[image]

Curiously, this only happens when I use `stat_func=None`. This is my calling command:

```
sns.jointplot(x=data[:,1], y=data[:,2], 
    kind="kde", space=0, color='blue', stat_func=None);
```

Ideally, I would like to have the blue background cover all the background so that I could also use `xlim` and `ylim` keywords. Alternatively, if I could crop the margins to where the KDE extends, it would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, passing `joint_kws={'shade_lowest':False}` solves this issue.

Comment: This seems to only remove the lowest density color instead of filling in the remaining background (that occurs when you set xlim/ylim).